# React. Generic handler for inputs

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a components:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import BeforeSubmitScreen from "./beforeSubmitScreen.jsx";

class SignUpStepOne extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isFormSubmitted: false,
      newCustomer: {
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: "",
        phone: "",
        password: ""
      }
    };
  }

  handleInputChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <BeforeSubmitScreen
        changed={this.handleInputChange}
        customer={this.state.newCustomer}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default SignUpStepOne;

import React from "react";

const beforeSubmitScreen = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        onChange={props.changed}
        name="firstName"
        value={props.customer.firstName}
      />

      <input
        onChange={props.changed}
        name="lastName"
        value={props.customer.lastName}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default beforeSubmitScreen;
```

I need to bind the inputs with model's properties using generic handler for all inputs in my component.

I am new in React. And I cannot understand where is my mistake...
What should I need to do?

Comment: What is the issue you're having?

Comment: When input's value was changed, I have a new property in component's state instead of changing current model's prop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `firstName` and `lastName` properties are part of the `newCustomer` object in your state, but you currently put it directly in the state object instead.

Put it in the `newCustomer` object and it will work as expected.

```
handleInputChange = e => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    newCustomer: { ...prevState.newCustomer, [name]: value }
  }));
};
```

```js
class SignUpStepOne extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isFormSubmitted: false,
      newCustomer: {
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: "",
        phone: "",
        password: ""
      }
    };
  }

  handleInputChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      newCustomer: { ...prevState.newCustomer, [name]: value }
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <BeforeSubmitScreen
        changed={this.handleInputChange}
        customer={this.state.newCustomer}
      />
    );
  }
}

const BeforeSubmitScreen = props => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input
        onChange={props.changed}
        name="firstName"
        value={props.customer.firstName}
      />

      <input
        onChange={props.changed}
        name="lastName"
        value={props.customer.lastName}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<SignUpStepOne />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```